# Reading space separated input in Python

Tags: python, input

Here is the input specification:

> The program has to read *t* lines of inputs. Each line consist of 2
> space separated values first one is the name and second is the age.
>
> An Example of input:
>
> ```
> Mike 18
> Kevin 35
> Angel 56
> ```

How to read this kind of input in Python? If I use `raw_input()`, both name and age are read in the same variable.

Comment: First grab some Python tutorial. Then learn how to use `split`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
the_string = input()
name, age = the_string.split()
```

In Python 2, use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: what if i have to read multiple integers like thousands or millions, and operate on them on the time of input.

Comment: raw_input isn't use in python 3 any more, you should use`list(map(str,input().split()))`

Answer (score 8):

If you have it in a string, you can use [`.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to separate them.

```
>>> for string in ('Mike 18', 'Kevin 35', 'Angel 56'):
...   l = string.split()
...   print repr(l[0]), repr(int(l[1]))
...
'Mike' 18
'Kevin' 35
'Angel' 56
>>>
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are on Python 3, you can use this syntax

```
inputs = list(map(str,input().split()))
```

if you want to access individual element you can do it like that

```
m, n = map(str,input().split())
```

Comment: that won't work because first item is not an integer

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following if you already know the number of fields of the input:

```
client_name = raw_input("Enter you first and last name: ")
first_name, last_name = client_name.split()
```

and in case you want to iterate through the fields separated by spaces, you can do the following:

```
some_input = raw_input() # This input is the value separated by spaces
for field in some_input.split():
    print field # this print can be replaced with any operation you'd like
    #             to perform on the fields.
```

A more generic use of the "split()" function would be:

```
    result_list = some_string.split(DELIMITER)
```

where DELIMETER is replaced with the delimiter you'd like to use as your separator, with single quotes surrounding it.

An example would be:

```
    result_string = some_string.split('!')
```

The code above takes a string and separates the fields using the '!' character as a delimiter.

Comment: How to separate input as individual characters without any whitespace in between. For example, I want the input ABC to be read in the matrix as 'A', 'B', 'C'. I am aware that I can use list("ABC") to separate but I want to use split() instead.

Answer (score 2):

For python 3 it would be like this 
`n,m,p=map(int,input().split())`

Answer (score 1):

For python 3 use this

```
inp = list(map(int,input().split()))
#input => java is a programming language
#return as => ("java","is","a","programming","language")
```

input() accepts a string from STDIN.

`split()` splits the string about whitespace character and returns a list of strings.

`map()` passes each element of the 2nd argument to the first argument and returns a map object

Finally `list()` converts the map to a list

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[]
for j in range(3):
    a.append([int(i) for  i in input().split()])
```

In this above code the given input i.e Mike 18 Kevin 35 Angel 56, will be stored in an array 'a' and gives the output as [['Mike', '18'], ['Kevin', '35'], ['Angel', '56']].

Answer (score 0):

Space separated values inside an array with specific range:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))[:n]
```

here n is denoting the maximum length of list.

Answer (score -2):

For Python3:

```
a, b = list(map(str, input().split()))
v = int(b)
```