# Need to take input in a row separated by space and reverse it

Tags: python, python-3.x

Need to take input in a row and separated by space, reverse it and add bot the outputs

I have tried raw_input().split()

```
for i in raw_input("Enter the numbers: ").split():
   print(i)
```

If array A has elements [1,2,3], then reverse of the array A will be [3,2,1] and the resultant array should be [4,4,4].

```
Input:
4
2 5 3 1

Output:
3 8 8 3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Space separated input in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637957/reading-space-separated-input-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get list from string of numbers divided with space you can use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). To iterate over list you can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map). [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) is used to iterate over list from end to start, [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) - to join elements of oroginal list with reversed and pass result to [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum). [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) join elements of list with provided delimiter.

Code ***(python 2)***:

```
limit = raw_input("Enter amount of numbers: ")
if limit.decode("utf-8").isdecimal():       # check if string contains only digits
    inp = raw_input("Enter the numbers: ")
    if int(limit) <= inp.count(" ") + 1:    # amount of spaces + 1 is amount of numbers
        a = map(int, inp.split(" "))        # split string and convert str to int
        b = map(sum, zip(a, reversed(a)))   # sum elements of input list and reversed
        res = " ".join(map(str, b))         # convert result to str and join to string
```

Code ***(python 3)***:

```
limit = input("Enter amount of numbers: ")
if limit.isdecimal():
    inp = input("Enter the numbers: ")
    if int(limit) <= inp.count(" ") + 1:
        a = list(map(int, inp.split(" ")))
        b = list(map(sum, zip(a, reversed(a))))
        res = " ".join(map(str, b))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I wanted the user to first ask that for many numbers he/she want to do this.

Comment: @AnkitRohilla, this code will work with any amount of numbers, so I find it useless to ask amount of numbers, cause there's nothing to do with this amount.

Comment: But sir I need to limit it, I don't want it to be unlimited. Can I first ask the user for the number of elements and then match it with the length of the elements entered?

Comment: @AnkitRohilla, yes, ofc. See post updates.

Comment: @AnkitRohilla, sorry, missed colon after condition.

Comment: This is the error which am getting now:

  File "/Users/ankit.rohilla/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 1, in <module>
    limit = raw_input()

NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: @AnkitRohilla, you switched to python3?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ankit.rohilla/PycharmProjects/Training/Test.py", line 2, in <module>
    if limit.isdecimal():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdecimal'

Comment: @AnkitRohilla, choose one version of python and use code for it. All errors you show caused by wrong version of python.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a tons of ways to solve this.
You can try this, probably.

```
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
assert n == len(arr)
result = list(map(lambda elem: elem[0] + elem[1], zip(arr, reversed(arr))))
print(result)
```

or just

```
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
assert n == len(arr)
for i, elem in enumerate(arr):
    print(elem + arr[n-i-1], end=' ')
```

Feel free to ask about it.

Comment: he's using python2 (cause he uses `raw_input()`), so replace `input()` with `raw_input()` and don't cast result of map to list. And, you don't need to write custom lambda there, it's already done in `sum()`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght his tag is python3.x

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
a=[2,5,3,1]
b = [x + y for x, y in zip(a, a[::-1])]
print(b) # -> [3, 8, 8, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t =int(input())
l = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
if len(l)==t:
    res =[str(i+j) for i,j in zip(l,l[::-1])]
    print(' '.join(res))
```

input

```
10
122 31 13123 234 13 1431 1 4 22 11
```

output

```
 133 53 13127 235 1444 1444 235 13127 53 133
```

Comment: what if number will have 2 digits?

Comment: Yah, It didn't worked

Comment: @OlvinRoght , it will work

Comment: @AnkitRohilla i is working for me , she the input format you need to give to run it

Comment: I need the output to be in the form of an array or list, it is needed to be in the same format as in which input was given.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ankit.rohilla/PycharmProjects/Training/Test.py", line 2, in <module>
    l = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
  File "<string>", line 1
    1 2 3
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @AnkitRohilla this code is working in python 3.6 fine, which python you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Very readable solution using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
l = [1, 2, 3]
np.add(l, np.flip(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be like this:

```
# creating an empty list
lst = []
# number of elemetns as input
n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))

# iterating till the range
for i in range(0, n):
    ele = int(input())
    lst.append(ele)  # adding the element
print(lst)
l = [l1 + l2 for l1, l2 in zip(lst, lst[::-1])]
print(l) 
ss=( ", ".join( repr(e) for e in l ) ) ## for not getting list as output
ss=ss.replace(","," ")
print((ss))
```

[image: This image is the output of my code.]

Comment: It didn't work, the solution provided by Olvin worked but its not complete.

Comment: Hey, @AnkitRohilla
This code works. You just need to enter the number of element first. then you need to eneter the numbers. and you will get the output. let me attach the screenshot of the output.

Comment: yah this works but I do not want the output to be in the form of array or lists. I want it to be just numberes in a single row separated by spaces.

Comment: @AnkitRohilla You can check the code now.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ankit.rohilla/PycharmProjects/Training/Test.py", line 8, in <module>
    ele = int(input())
  File "<string>", line 1
    1 2 3
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax