# How do you read whitespaces in a string?

Tags: python, dictionary

The question is to calculate the time required by a robotic hand to type a message in a mobile keypad ( the old keypads that mobiles used to have, before the invention of screentouch). The initial position of the hand is in key 1.

For example: ***if its supposed to type "hack" it will take 1 second to move from key 1 to key 4 and then 2 seconds to type "h".
Now again 1 second to move from key 4 to key 2 and then 1 second to type "a".
Since "c" is present at the same key as "a" movement time is 0. So it simply takes 3 seconds to type "c".
Finally it moves from key 2 to key 5 in 1 second and then 2 seconds to type "k". So in total it took 1+2+1+1+3+1+2= 11 seconds to type "hack".***

This is my code for the above problem:

```
testcases=int(input())
position=1
seconds=0
dictionary={1:".,;?", 2:"abc", 3:"def", 4:"ghi", 5:"jkl", 6:"mno", 
               7:"pqrs", 8:"tuv", 9:"wxyz", 0:" " }
numbers=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']


for test in range(testcases):
    string=input()
    for character in string:
        if character in numbers:
            if position==character:
                seconds+=1
            else:
                position=character
                seconds+=2
        else:
            for keys in dictionary.keys():
                if character in dictionary[keys]:
                    if int(position)==keys:
                        seconds+=dictionary[keys].index(character)+1
                    else:
                        position=keys
                        seconds+=dictionary[keys].index(character)+2
                    break
    print(seconds)
    position,seconds=1,0
```

It works fine, but now the problem is how do I read the empty spaces in the string?

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with the code. It does process spaces correctly as far as I can tell.

Comment: What do you mean by empty spaces. Is it pressing the spacebar or something else.

Comment: Suppose the string is `"hacker earth"` then the space in between will take around 2 seconds to type ( pressing 0 twice will give space)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading Space separated input in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637957/reading-space-separated-input-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string module.

```py
import string
dictionary={1:".,;?", 2:"abc", 3:"def", 4:"ghi", 5:"jkl", 6:"mno", 
               7:"pqrs", 8:"tuv", 9:"wxyz", 0:string.whitespace}
```

Then check if the key entered is a whitespace.

```py
if key in dictionary.get(0):
    print('Whitespace is entered.')
```